# CNAMEレコードは使わないほうがいい？

Tags: dns

ドメインの追加をする際に最近では"CNAMEレコード"は使わないと聞きました。
`domain.jp`／`www.domain.jp`を登録する場合、両方とも"Aレコード"に追加するようです。

"CNAMEレコード"を使わない理由は何でしょうか？

自分でパッと思い当たる理由としては
レコードを検索しにいくからサーバに負荷をかける……とかでしょうか？
ハッキリとした理由が思い浮かばないので教えて頂ければと思います。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> domain.jp／www.domain.jpを登録する場合、両方とも"Aレコード"に追加するようです。

CNAMEを設定した場合、同じキーのレコードは登録してはいけないので、`domain.jp` の CNAMEレコードを使ってしまうと、SOA、NS、MX などが書けないということになりますので、`domain.jp` の CNAMEは使いません（使えません）。

> "CNAMEレコード"を使わない理由は何でしょうか？

だからといって「最近では"CNAMEレコード"は使わない」ということにはなりませんが…、使わない理由としてはこの辺りではないでしょうか。

1. CNAME でなくても Aレコードで大抵は問題ないので使う理由がない(例外もある)
2. CNAMEで別ゾーンのレコードにマッピングする場合は別ゾーンのDNSの影響を受けます。別ゾーンの管理が他者であれば、他人任せということになりますので それを嫌う場合は CNAMEは使わない。

Comment: 転送する際に管理者が別だと気になりますね。もっと重々しい理由があるのかと思いました。ありがとうございます。